# Read single value from a table

Tags: tables, macros, pgfplotstable

I will use in many places in my LaTeX document a specific value given in, say, the row 2 and column 1 from a table. Is it possible to make a macro for it, such as \read{2}{1} ?

Here is an simple example of a table, from which I want to read the value 22.

```
   \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
      height 20
      length 21
      depth 22
    \end{filecontents}
```

Comment: There is already one. See `\pgfplotstablegetelem{}{}` in the manual.

Comment: For general use (outside of pgfplotstable), there is also the `readarray` package.

Comment: I will need to use the value outside of the pgfplots environment in my case :)